# iOS Apple Pay in-App provisioning extension: `viewDidLoad` method not called after invoking `init`

Tags: applepay, apple-wallet

I am coding for Apple Pay in-App provisioning extension, but there was a problem when Apple Wallet load authorization UI extension:
[shotscreen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W1uQL.png)

The source code:

```
// The principal class .h file
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_BEGIN

@interface IssuerProvisioningViewController : UIViewController

@end

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_END

// The principal class .m file
#import "IssuerProvisioningViewController.h"
#import <PassKit/PassKit.h>

@interface IssuerProvisioningViewController ()<PKIssuerProvisioningExtensionAuthorizationProviding>

@end

@implementation IssuerProvisioningViewController

@synthesize completionHandler;

- (instancetype)init {
    NSLog(@"--- init");
    self = [super init];
    return self;
}

- (instancetype)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil {
    NSLog(@"--- initWithNibName nibNameOrNil");
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    NSLog(@"viewDidLoad");
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
}

@end
```

The Info.plist:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>NSExtension</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSExtensionPointIdentifier</key>
        <string>com.apple.PassKit.issuer-provisioning.authorization</string>
        <key>NSExtensionPrincipalClass</key>
        <string>IssuerProvisioningViewController</string>
    </dict>
</dict>
</plist>
```

The entitlement file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>com.apple.developer.payment-pass-provisioning</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Environment:

1. iOS 16.4.1

Thanks for reading and any advice.

I found the method `viewDidLoad` was not be called after invoking method `init`.

Comment: [Apple Dev Forums](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/730727)

Comment: Hi, you had success on this wallet extension I have also faced the same problem.
How are you invoicing IssuerUIExtension from top-level UIVIewController

Answer (score 0):

`NSExtensionPointIdentifier` should be `com.apple.PassKit.issuer-provisioning` according to Apple Pay In-App Provisioning Extensions for Payment Cards guide.

Comment: Hey @pirags ,But NSExtensionPointIdentifier should be com.apple.PassKit.issuer-provisioning.authorization for authorization UI extension. Issuers need to provide the authorization UI extension using the endpoint ‘com.apple.PassKit.issuer- provisioning.authorization’. The principal class of the extension needs to be a subclass of UIViewController that adopts the protocol PKIssuerProvisioningExtensionAuthorizationProviding

Answer (score 0):

I'm also running into the same issue. Have no idea how to fix.

However from observing the phone logs for PassBook process (I viewed logs on device using the console app on macos) I can see the following
`PKIssuerProvisioningExtensionAuthorizationViewController: failed to find matching authorization UI extension for <private>.`

Comment: Any progress? I got the solution from [Apple Developer Forums](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/730727)

Comment: I got past my original issue. But now when i fire the completion handler nothing happens.